# Android App responding to USSD

Tags: android, ussd

Im Trying to develop an APP that responds to an USSD menu, can anyone give any pointer on how to respond on the menu USSD programmatically, i covered the part were to dial the fisrt USSD but how to repond on the secod menu???

Comment: What menu are you talking about?

Comment: Telecom Operators usually offer certain services using USSD Ex. *173# which will open a dialog menu to respond to, this is the menu im talking about

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the mobile operator you wish to integrate with or if you will be using a third party to facilitate your connectivity with mobile operators.

It also depends on whether you specified that the session is to be a continuing session when you displayed the first menu. This could be in the form of keywords such as CON or NEXTSTATE.

Majority of the mobile operators use HTTP so as long as you maintain the HTTP connection with them you can have interactive sessions.